# How to rescale data to its original range after MinMaxScaler?

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-science, data-preprocessing

I'm using `sklearn`'s MinMaxScaler in order to scale my data down. However, it would be nice to be able to rescale it back to its original range. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [`inverse_transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.inverse_transform) of the created `MinMaxScaler` object.

See also [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41551165/3924118) for other answers and examples.